# Does inotify enqueue events synchronously?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I'm trying to use `inotify` for monitoring file-system modifications. In particular I'm trying to catch all updates for file in some pre-configured directory.

The problem arose when I'm trying to switch off the application with `SIGTERM`. I want all modifications are to be processed prior to that.

***QUESTION:*** If the only process doing file modification (`write`ing/`mv`ing) terminated is it reliable to say that if The `FIONREAD` `ioctl` returns 0 then all modification were retrieved from `inotify` file descriptor. [The documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) specifies:

> The `FIONREAD ioctl(2)` returns the number of bytes available to read
>   from an inotify file descriptor.

So I would assume if no events in the queue left after the process doing all the modifications is shutdown than all events are read from the inotify descriptor and no one will arrive later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can highly recommend you use `signalfd`, see [this man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

With this signals are delivered down a pipe, instead signal actions being run asynchronously. This way you can use a reactor like `select()` or `epoll()` to wait on both the inotify pipe and the `signalfd()` file descriptor, allowing you to tidily manage when you actually read the signal from the fd and process it.

And, because you're handling the signal synchronously within the main loop of the programme instead of in an asynchronous signal action, there's no limits on what functions you can call whilst dealing with the signal.

In my humble opinion `signalfd()` is far, far, far superior to the nasty old way of handling signals. The only minor downside is that it is (AFAIK) not portable to other *nixes.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that after `read(signalfd)` returns the signal specified in the mask (term) and if the termination was initiatiated after all fs modification were made I can empty the inotify queue and be sure no other events will arrive?

Comment: Basically, yes. If you read a TERM from the signalfd, you merely need to set a flag remembering, "I have been told to terminate". Next time select() times out on the inotify pipe, simply quit the programme.

Comment: AFAIK, all of inotify is not portable to other Unix-like systems, so there's no change in the portability (except perhaps to older variants of inotify).

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler :-)

Comment: @bazza The thing is that shutting down as soon as possible is cricitical in my case so I cannot really wait on `select` times out. Would the following scenario work: The mutator process does some filesystem mutation and when it is done it sends a signal to the watching process. When the watching process receives the signal it inspects the inotify queue via `FIONREAD` and drains it. Is there a possibility for losing event? I mean are there some gaps between say writing to a file and enqueing the related event in the inotify queue? Did not find anything in `man inotify(7)` on that.

Comment: @SomeName, yes you could do that. You could also have a zero timeout on select() after receipt of the TERM. That way you'd be polling the inotify fd, and as soon as it was empty you'd quit immediately. With both methods, there may the be potential for a race between the two processes and the kernel. I don't know enough about how inotify works in the kernel to know whether the inotify fd would be guaranteed to contain every outstanding change. But you could test it. Go with a long timeout on select(), and measure whether anything shows up in the inotify fd after intially draining it.

Comment: @SomeName, you could also have the mutator make an FS change purely for the purposes of saying "That's the last change". Could be a change to a file called `alldone.txt`. That would allow you to get confident with whether or not there's potential for a race in TERM and inotify. If you never find that the inotify data for this file turns up later than expected, you could then be confident that it's not necessary

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things being conflated in this question and the accepted answer.

To answer the heart of the question:

If the only process that is changing files in the watched location has terminated, then you can terminate when there are no more events in the inotify queue.  You can safely check the size by inspecting `FIONREAD` as you mentioned in the question.  In order for this to not miss any events, you need to know for sure that the mutating process has definitely finished through some other means; the critical aspect of this is that you don't want to finish processing the inotify queue until the mutating process has finished, and your inotify process has received `SIGTERM`.

However, if you don't know whether the other process has finished, but want to make sure that events up to the current point in time (eg: when `SIGTERM` is detected) have been processed, you will need to employ a technique similar to that used in `watchman`.  The concept is that you would create a special marker file with a magic name in the watched directory when your main process is asked to terminate.  Then you would continue to process events from the inotify queue until you see your magic file name; at that point you can tell that all events prior to the magic file creation have been consumed.  There is more information about this technique here: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cookies.html  (disclaimer: I'm the creator of watchman)

The discussion about `signalfd` vs. traditional signal handling is orthogonal to the timing aspect of this question: you can certainly use the original posix signal handling interface and set a global variable to indicate that `SIGTERM` has been received.  It doesn't change anything about the sequencing or timing of inotify events, so feel free to use whichever method you like when implementing that.

Comment: Since `inotify` queue is an ordered queue then creating the marker file and catching an event for the file does really make sense. Thanks. The thing that I'm still confused about is the "ordering consistency". Say I have a mutator process that does some filesystem mutation in some directory and when it is done it sends `sigterm` to the process listening for the changes via `inotify`. Is it guaranteed that all the changes done before sending the signal by the mutator process is visible after receiving the signal by the watching process so I can use `FIONREAD` ioctl to drain `inotify` queue.

Comment: If you didn't mind calling inotify_rm_watch, could you call this and wait for the IN_IGNORED event for your second case (events up until the current point in time)?